# BoringSSL Error when I compile my App in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, xcode9

I made an App with "Google Firebase" as my back-end.

I want my App to be able to send push notifications, and actually, I have all setted up, however, when I compile my App, it builds perfectly and without errors and warnings, but in the console, this error appears:

> **[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length**

And then, I send a push notification from "Google Firebase" to my app, but it never recieves it. I don't know how to handle this error. Has anyone had the same issue?

I'm using Xcode 9 GM Seed / Build: 9A235. My device is an iPhone 6 with iOS 11.

Here I leave the complete sentence that appears in the console, appart from the error:

```
2017-09-14 09:39:17.042434+0200 pushApp[288:15360] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40003000 started
2017-09-14 09:39:17.111 pushApp[288] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40003000 started
2017-09-14 09:39:17.111336+0200 pushApp[288:15360] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo .gl/RfcP7r)
2017-09-14 09:39:17.113 pushApp[288] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo .gl/RfcP7r)
2017-09-14 09:39:17.249119+0200 pushApp[288:15366] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1754 received sct extension length is less than sct data length
Token: diArDpk_ugc:APA91bEEhAnZJlSr8nGUyGqGn8bSbxD3VpGAbIMoCLREBqeD2bkQcOVlpZJecc5g0ptosLtxpVOqboeIKiX7odWf28p551f0m1G_no-sAmNzXKAgSIM4nOtkNJJCMWJO1LJ6ItsYlgX2
2017-09-14 09:39:17.287687+0200 pushApp[288:15271] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 1
2017-09-14 09:39:17.287784+0200 pushApp[288:15271] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-09-14 09:39:17.287825+0200 pushApp[288:15271] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
2017-09-14 09:39:17.393859+0200 pushApp[288:15371] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-09-14 09:39:17.394711+0200 pushApp[288:15371] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-09-14 09:40:40.132473+0200 pushApp[288:15751] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2017-09-14 09:40:40.132573+0200 pushApp[288:15751] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
```

Comment: Did you find the cause? I'm running into the same issue and the internet is awefully quiet about the BoringSSL-stuff. Gracias!

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but I'm just making a simple network request. Although everything works fine, so not sure what this warning is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix in the latest versions of Firebase, FirebaseMessaging and FirebaseInstanceID check this comments [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/314#issuecomment-332339019) and the [last here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/315)

You should try to update your pods

Comment: This message still there in Xcode 9 GM but not in the 9.1 beta (9B37)

Comment: Well no, the message Borring SSL -> "BoringSSL" is an output by Xcode 9 when an SSL connection is established (which FCM and IID SDKs do, as others), but is not related to whether something is working or not. The fact that your notifications weren't received should be fixed, about the borring ssl message itself, it will disappear with the latest version of Xcode ;-)